# If logic where either of two conditions make it true

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to delete a row if cells in column V is not equal to F or V.

This code deletes everything.

```vb
For i = RowCount To 1 Step -1
    If Range("V" & i).Value <> "F" Or Range("V" & i).Value <> "V" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
```

Comment: Change the `Or` to `And`

Comment: Logic is wrong. If you're checking for `(x not A) OR (x not B)` this will always be true if A and B are not the same.

Comment: are the contents upper case?

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner  Sometimes you have been looking at the screen so long that things don't make sense anymore.

Comment: or a bit shorter `If Not Cells(i, "V") Like "[FV]" Then Rows(i).Delete`

Comment: Hey, can you go ahead and accept my answer? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems incorrect. By changing the `or` to an `and`, you will then be evaluating the proper boolean arithmetic.

Right now, you are checking `not "v"` and `not "f"` which is always false.
No matter the input, this will always have answer be true.

Comment: I don't and many people don't go to the comments before the answers. An answer should always be left so that if anyone comes along with the same question as OP, the answer is easily visible with a green check - not hidden in the comments.

Comment: Fair enough but there are quite a large amount of questions that only get answered in comments. Whatever though :)

Comment: @DougCoats comments can't be marked as accepted, and don't earn anyone rep score - if someone answers questions in comments, it's their loss. Common courtesy would be to link to the comment in the answer though.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I realized as i was typing that people getting creds is a thing. I could delete my comment or accept that im wrong and move on. Ive chosen the latter :D

Comment: You can comment under their post and kindly link to [this Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), or to [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/197901) on meta; they'll get the ping and hopefully take the hint. But whether they accept an answer or not is at their entire discretion. Just keep answering - most people are happy to mark a good helpful answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to
[Else Not working in "If Then Else" in VBA EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642028/else-not-working-in-if-then-else-in-vba-excel)

You need something similar

```
Sub SpecificFlatArrears03()
    
    Dim Flat As Variant
    
    Do
        Flat = InputBox("Pl Enter a Flat Number as 3 Digit without Prefix")
        'at this point you should check that Flat meets the required requirements
        Range("h3").Value = Flat
        If (Flat > 100 And Flat < 165) Or (Flat > 200 And Flat < 264) Or (Flat > 300 And Flat < 364) Or Flat = 403 Or Flat = 404 Or Flat = 462 Or Flat = 463 Then
            Range("h4") = WorksheetFunction.Match(Flat, Range("'2020-2021'!d11:d206"), 0)
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until False
    
End Sub
```