# Else Not working in "If Then Else" in VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in VBA Excel, also I don't know how to express my thanks to the author of helpful answer thru this site.
I am looking for the position of some particular numbers in a column. The following code works perfectly when the number is included in the column but gives error when the number is not valid although I put a Label (Again). It seems the sub does not see the Label. The numbers are 101 to 164, 201 to 264, 301 to 364 and 403,404,462 and 463.

```vb
Sub SpecificFlatArrears03()
    Dim Flat As Integer
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim demand As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    
Again:
    Flat = InputBox("Pl Enter a Flat Number as 3 Digit without Prefix")
    
    Range("h3").Value = Flat
    
    If Flat > 100 Or Flat < 165 Then
        GoTo Arrears            
    End If
        
    If Flat > 200 Or Flat < 264 Then
        GoTo Arrears
    End If
        
    If Flat > 300 Or Flat < 364 Then
        GoTo Arrears
    End If
        
    If Flat = 403 Or Flat = 404 Or Flat = 462 Or Flat = 463 Then
        GoTo Arrears
    Else: GoTo Again
    End If
    
Arrears:
    x = WorksheetFunction.Match(Flat, Range("'2020-2021'!d11:d206"), 0)
    
    Range("h4").Value = x
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the problem is the ':' after `else`.

Comment: @Luuk No, the problem is that any number satisfies `If Flat > 100 Or Flat < 165`.

Comment: well I know you are a beginner, but just a few keywords to improve that code: have a look at 'ElseIf' or a switch case statement.  Don't use goto, use loops or functions. It makes no difference in that case, but you lose all the control with a goto, while a loop or a function always hands control back